# EmailID field not inserted in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to implement CRUD using JSP, Struts2 & Hibernate. I'm referring to example explained [here](http://www.tutorials4u.net/struts2-tutorial/struts2_crud_example.html)
I included additional field EmailID in my jsp form. I also included the field in User.java. Project runs without any errors or warnings. But when I try to insert a record using the JSP form... everything except email ID field is inserted to mySQL database(same goes for EDIT option). Please see the attached screen shot below for reference. I need help to understand if I've missed something to add. 
Following is the code from both files.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
<s:head />
<style type="text/css">
@import url(style.css);
</style>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser">
<s:push value="user">
    <s:hidden name="id" />
    <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name" />
    <s:radio name="gender" label="Gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" />
    <s:select name="country" list="{'India','USA','UK'}" headerKey=""
        headerValue="Select" label="Select a country" />
    <s:textarea name="aboutYou" label="About You" />
    <s:checkbox name="mailingList"
        label="Would you like to join our mailing list?" />
            <s:textfield name="emailid" label="Email ID" />
    <s:submit />
</s:push>
</s:form>

<s:if test="userList.size() > 0">
<div class="content">
<table class="userTable" cellpadding="5px">
    <tr class="even">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>About You</th>
        <th>Mailing List</th>
                    <th>Email ID</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="userList" status="userStatus">
        <tr
            class="<s:if test="#userStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="gender" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="country" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="aboutYou" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="mailingList" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="emailid" /></td>
            <td><s:url id="editURL" action="editUser">
                <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
            </s:url> <s:a href="%{editURL}">Edit</s:a></td>
            <td><s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteUser">
                <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
            </s:url> <s:a href="%{deleteURL}">Delete</s:a></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
</div>
</s:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is code from User.Java

```
package com.tutorials4u.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String gender;
private String country;
private String aboutYou;
    private String emailid;
private Boolean mailingList;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USER_ID") 
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="USER_NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="USER_GENDER")
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Column(name="USER_COUNTRY")
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

    @Column(name="USER_EMAILID")
    public String getEmailID() {
    return emailid;
}
public void setEmailID(String emailid) {
    this.emailid = emailid;
}

@Column(name="USER_ABOUT_YOU")
public String getAboutYou() {
    return aboutYou;
}
public void setAboutYou(String aboutYou) {
    this.aboutYou = aboutYou;
}

@Column(name="USER_MAILING_LIST")
public Boolean getMailingList() {
    return mailingList;
}
public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
    this.mailingList = mailingList;
}



}
```

[Screen shot of JSP form... EmailID is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Redfp.jpg)

Comment: `emailid` != `emailID`.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, could you please elaborate? Thank you very much for quick reply...

Comment: You are submitting `emailid`. What property is should be mapped to? Why?

Comment: I'm trying to map it to property emailid. I'm trying to add fields one by one in existing jsp form and database. So I started with EmailID field.

Comment: How your private `emailid` property will be set?

Comment: understood... now its working. But now makes me wonder why the existing solution is working with private properties (available at - http://www.tutorials4u.net/struts2-tutorial/struts2_crud_example.html).

Comment: What? Fields should be private.

Comment: @NVJ the existing solution doesn't have any emailID (and hence no capitalization typos). Use your IDE to generate getters and setters (In Eclipse `ALT+SHIFT+S+R`) except when the first word is one letter long, because it does it in a way Struts2 doesn't like.

Comment: Hi, here is what is happening. in user.java if I declare emailid as private, the field is not inserted in DB. But when I change it to public String emailid - the field is inserted in DB.

Comment: Because you have the wrong getters and setters: you have `setEmailID()` and `getEmailID()`, while you need `setEmailid()` and `getEmailid()`.

Comment: ok... got it. Its working now.,,, Thank you very much Andrea & Aleksandr.